# Restrict xml attribute to be equal to the specific value only 1 time among the children using xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to implement a *restriction for an attribute* in .xsd schema.

I have `default` attribute (boolean), which should have **exactly 1** `true` value among all children. The attribute is not required, ommitting it should mean the same as `false` value.

**Valid:**

```xml
<Parent>
  <Child default="true">One</Child>
  <Child default="false">Two</Child>
  <Child>Three</Child>
</Parent>
```

**Valid:**

```xml
<Parent>
  <Child default="true">One</Child>
  <Child>Two</Child>
  <Child>Three</Child>
</Parent>
```

**Not valid:**

```xml
<Parent>
  <Child default="true">One</Child>
  <Child>Two</Child>
  <Child default="true">Three</Child>
</Parent>
```

**Not valid:** (no elements with default="true", should be at least 1)

```xml
<Parent>
  <Child>One</Child>
  <Child>Two</Child>
  <Child>Three</Child>
</Parent>
```

**So the question:**
Is it possible to implement such a restriction using .xsd?

If yes, how?

Comment: I don't think you can express this in pure XML Schema 1.0, you need either an XML Schema 1.1 assertion or something like schematron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're using XML Schema 1.1**, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via XPath 2.0 using `xs:assert` like this (untested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Parent">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Child" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="default" type="xs:boolean">
                </xs:attribute>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count('./Child[@default = true]') = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**If you're using XML Schema 1.0**, you cannot express such a constraint in the schema, but you could use [Schematron](http://xml.ascc.net/resource/schematron/) or check it at the application level.